# How to test the case when there is no ad available?

Tags: android, admob

I'm using Madvertise, Mobfox and Admob to monetize my Android apps. Madvertise is my primary choice and the others are supposed to fill in ads when there is no Mad ad available. Is there a way to test the case when there is no Madvertise or Mobfox ad? I want to test whether the backfill mechanism works.

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a fake publisher ID by adding nonsense to the end. (e.g. TestToknNONSENSE for Madvertise).

Answer (score 1):

Try to block the content servers of Madvertise and Mobfox with your firewall or the `hosts` file. This should work more realistic.